# How to change default gateway on XP VPN connection?

Tags: vpn, windows-xp, gateway

When I connect to an XP VPN the default gateway for the connection is the IP address of the VPN server machine.

I think this is the reason I cannot connect to the internet via the VPN.

How do I change the default gateway of the VPN connection to the IP address of the remote router?

Answer (score 3):

Disable the option **`Use default gateway on remote network.`** You can find this bygoing to network connections and clicking the Advanced button in the properties page of Internet Protocol Version 4 (or 6) of your VPN connection.

[Why do I lose internet when making a VPN connection?](http://diaryproducts.net/about/operating_systems/windows/enable_disable_default_gateway_vpn_windows)

Comment: No, this causes the gateway to be blank. I want it to be the remote router's IP address.

Comment: When you disable the option, you WILL BE allowed to connect to the Internet. Have you tried it??

Comment: Yes, it doesn't allow me to connect via the VPN. It tries to connect through my local gateway which is not what I want.

Comment: Disabling the option does not disable access to the VPN. I've set this up on several computers, and when you can't connect to the internet after connecting to your VPN it's a routing issue. I've attached a link for you to take look it. Sorry if it wasn't helpful

Comment: OK thanks. Where is the link?  Can I route traffic from the VPN connection to the remote router?

Comment: The link is in my answer, "Why do I lose internet when making a VPN connection?" :). On what side is the remote router, I'm assuming it's on the VPN tunnel end

Comment: The remote router is on the side of the VNP server. I simply want to use internet connection of remote network.

Comment: The VPN endpoint would have to have IP forwarding enabled on it for this to work, or else traffic wouldn't know how to route itself through the tunnel. This is why you use your own local gateway for internet connections

Comment: I have enabled IP forwarding in the registry of the VPN server machine, but it still doesn't work.  Are there any tests I can do to see what is actually the problem.  Tracert etc?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3271/discussion-between-ovi-borrero-and-craigj)

Comment: It's not letting me login to chat. I am only using standard VPN server on XP-Pro and standard VPN connection from XP-Pro.